# Kafka consumer.poll returning empty

Tags: java, apache-kafka

The producer code which will read a `.mp4` video file from disc and sends it to kafka which apparently works since prints `"Message sent to the Kafka Topic java_in_use_topic Successfully"`, but the `consumer.poll` is empty:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/javainuse-kafka/")
public class ApacheKafkaWebController {
@GetMapping(value = "/producer")
public String producer(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    // list of host:port pairs used for establishing the initial connections to the Kakfa cluster
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            "localhost:9092");
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getName());
    Producer<String, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    Path path = Paths.get("C:/kafka-picture-consumer/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4");
    ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> record = null;
    try {
        record = new ProducerRecord<>("topiccc", "keyyyyy", Files.readAllBytes(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    producer.send(record);
    producer.close();
    return "Message sent to the Kafka Topic java_in_use_topic Successfully";
}
```

The consumer code which will be used in a `servlet`:

```
public class ConsumerService {
    public byte[] consumer(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "test");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topiccc"));
        ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = consumer.poll(100);
       System.out.println("ISSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS EMPTYYYYYYYYYY:"+String.valueOf(records.isEmpty()));
        return records.iterator().next().value();
    }
}
```

Comment: If poll returned null, like your title claims,  you’d get a NullPointeeException. Pleas correct your question.

Comment: The dacht that your producer prints “Message sent to the Kafka Topic java_in_use_topic Successfully” doesn’t mean that it  was successful, as your catch block only prints the exception, it doesn’t rethrow it, so you get the success message even when the producer fails (perhaps your message is larger than the maximum message size for the topic?)

Comment: When do you use the producer and the consumer? Are you "waiting" enough time for the message to arrive? 
You can always use the console tools to ensure the topic is not empty

Answer (score 1):

There can be many possible reasons for this:

1. Your producer is not sending the message. If this is the case, you can check it by adding callback to your producer and printing the exception. If the exception is null, then the send() is successful.

   producer.send(record, (recordMetadata, exception) -> {
        System.err.println(exception);
   });

Since you are sending an `mp4` file, I suppose that you might not have set your Kafka broker configurations and/or topic configurations to support such a large message.
Check the `max.message.bytes` and `message.max.bytes` configurations of topic and broker. In this case, you will get `RecordTooLargeException`

2. You will have to wait till the producer completely produces the message.
3. You will need to set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest` in your consumer configurations. This ensures that if no offset data is there for that topic, then it will start consuming from the first message, otherwise it will wait for the next message.
4. Your `poll` duration is short, you may need to increase this.